# VBA and Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

pretty new with VBA and there doesnt seem to be much help around the internet as I understand it is relativley old.

I am trying to use a Macro to submit data from an excel sheet into a SQL server DB.

Basically the click of a button, should pull the required data from the cells, which then put the data in the correct columns in my DB.

It is not submitting the data properley, for example one cell has the number '2' in it and it is submitting the number '0' into my database.

Can anyone advise?

Code below.

```
' Create the connection string.
sConnString = "provider=xxx; Data Source=xx-xxx; Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID= xx; Password=xxx;": MsgBox "Connection Succesful"



' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim val As String
val = Range("D5").Value

' Open the connection and execute.
conn.Open sConnString

Dim item As String
item = "INSERT INTO [Industrial].[dbo].[Header]("
item = item & "  [server_name]"
item = item & "  ,[date]"
item = item & "  ,[amendee]"
item = item & "  ,[ip_address]"
item = item & "  ,[physical_location]"
item = item & "  ,[host_name]"
item = item & "  ,[is_it_contact]"
item = item & "  ,[businesscontact]"
item = item & "  ,[businessdependencies]"
item = item & "  ,[backup_strategy_in_place]"
item = item & "  ,[physorvirt]"

item = item & "  )Values("
item = item & "  '" & val & "'"
item = item & "  '" & val & "'"
item = item & "  '" & val & "'"
item = item & "  '" & val & "'"
item = item & "  '" & val & "'"
item = item & "  '" & val & "'"
item = item & "  '" & val & "'"
item = item & "  '" & val & "'"
item = item & "  '" & val & "'"
item = item & "  '" & val & "'"
item = item & "  '" & val & "'"

conn.Execute item
```

End Sub

Comment: looks like you're taking the same value found in D5 and setting it as the value for each column of the DB record.. is that what you want?

Comment: Was just trying to add the 'D5' cell value to ,[ip_address] column which belongs in the [header] table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check the data types and the constraints on your DB table.  Its possible depending on your db type (MySQL, MSSQL, or Postgres) that if you're trying to put in a 'true' instead of true for a boolean column, it will default to 0.

Secondly, I notice is that you're placing the same value into every column.

Might I suggest an array.  (intro to excel vba Arrays: http://excelvbatutor.com/vba_chp21.htm)

The below code will work assuming your data is on Sheet1 and like so... 
     A               B  (columns)
1
2  column_name_B     "fifty"
3  column_name_C      10
4  column_name_D      myName
(rows)
    Sub testeroo()

```
Dim myArray(2, 2)
Dim x As Integer

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
For x = 2 To 4
    myArray(x - 2, 0) = Cells(x, 1).Value  'gets the title
    myArray(x - 2, 1) = Cells(x, 2).Value  'gets the value
Next x
```

Then you could do a loop through the array to get your SQL statement.
    End Sub

Comment: Although your answer was good!...I managed to get it working over night.

Comment: Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim val As String
    val = Range("B5").Value
    
    ' Open the connection and execute.
    conn.Open sConnString
    
    Dim item As String
    item = "INSERT INTO [IndustrialComp].[dbo].[Header]("
    item = item & "  [server_name]"
   

    item = item & "  )Values("
    item = item & "  '" & val & "')"
    
    conn.Execute item